# Your development team does not support the Push Notifications capability

Tags: ios

Showing All Messages

> Your development team, " ACCOUNT NAME", does not support the Push
>   Notifications capability.

Comment: Go to Target-> Capabilities-> turn on push notifications and update the App Id and provisioning profile accordingly

Comment: Do you have a free or paid program membership?

Comment: Shruti there's no 'Push Notification' option in 'Capabilities.

Comment: thank you Shruti, that fixed it for me! @D.Hodges there was a push notifications setting there, but once I clicked the trash icon next to it, it disappeared and everything worked. Granted, I don't need push notifications enabled

Answer (score 30):

There are 2 possibilities:

1. If your Apple account is not enrolled with developer program. Please get your apple account enrolled with the Apple developer program.
2. If your Account registered as an organization, you might be using the account of an individual person for "Signing Team". Please select the organization as "Signing Team".

Comment: No, the enrollment program is not free. It costs 99 USD/year.

Also, check that you have enabled Push Notification in Capabilities for your apple account.

Comment: If I can't have an enrollment program how can I test notifications "Free"?

Comment: You won't be able to test the push notifications unless the Apple account is not enrolled in the Apple Developer program.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that in the 'Team' list in Xcode, it had populated two entries, the individual and the company. I was trying to use the individual instead of the company, once I chose the company in the list, it worked.

Comment: how can I do the second step?

Answer (score 8):

When you login to AppStore Connect, under **Users and Access** menu you need to select the ***Access to Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles*** checkbox for your user.

### ---IMPORTANT---
**You will only the that option to be granted for a user if your Apple Developer Account is an Organization and NOT an Individual**. You need to contact Apple to change that.

After that, you will be able to see your team in Xcode and sign the application.
[image: iTunesConnect Users and Access]

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable push notifications in your capabilities and check if it is enabled in the developer portal. [Here](https://www.raywenderlich.com/8164-push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started) is a tutorial that will help.

Answer (score 1):

If your Apple account is not enrolled with developer program. Please get your apple account enrolled with the Apple developer program.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the following

- Select the development account when you choose automatic signing
- add the development certificate to the provision profile

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with a production app.

After a few phone calls from Apple we made changes to Build Settings and were able to compile again.

In Build Settings, set each element to Apple Development and the provisioning profile to Automatic (every element).

Had to make sure the MinimOSVersion was set in xCode, info.plist and Runner -> Flutter -> AppFrameworkInfo.plist

Hope this helps.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/718388?page=1#734346022