# Personal development teams, including " ***** ", do not support the Fonts capability

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator, simulator

I want to create an `IPA file in Xcode`, but when I am changing the team **none to some apple account**, I am getting this error.
Did anyone know who to tackle this problem?

Comment: Can you maybe add information about what capabilities you included in your app (e.g. what the Fonts capability is)? I suspect you are not using a paid developer account, so I think the problem is similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55828837/your-development-team-does-not-support-the-push-notifications-capability